# Getting geo coordinates from Google map

Tags: android, google-maps, coordinates

In my app,I enable the user to enter a new Marker or Markers in the google map. This is how I do it.

```
 public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    ready = true;
    mMap = googleMap;
    //UiSettings ui=mMap.getUiSettings();

    //ui.setZoomGesturesEnabled(false);

    MarkerOptions mo = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(MainActivity.lat),Double.parseDouble(MainActivity.lon))).title("Alcazar Stadium");

    googleMap.addMarker(mo);
    mo.draggable(true);
    mo.flat(true);
    //Click listener that allows the user to enter a new marker on the map!
    googleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
            MarkerOptions newMark = getMarker(latLng);
            mMap.addMarker(newMark);

        }
    });
}

private MarkerOptions getMarker(LatLng ln){
    count++;
    return  new MarkerOptions()
            .title("New")
            .snippet("Another Marker")
            .position(ln)
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ORANGE))
            .draggable(true);


}
```

With the help of the debugger I get the geo coordinates in the following form

```
lat/lng: (39.65502267075256,22.409939467906952)
```

Up to this to this point everything works ok,but I want to decouble the above response as

```
Latitute: 39.65502267075256
Longitude: 22.409939467906952
```

This is where I am stuck. Any ideas?

Thanks,

Theo.

Answer (score 0):

that was easy:)

```
 double lat = latLng.latitude;
 double log = latLng.longitude;
```